# extract features from caffe

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, feature-extraction

I hace a problem when facing extract features from Caffe. In this [tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/feature_extraction.html)  said that we can use `'extract_features.bin'` which stored in build folder. But, in my build folder, I cannot find this file. I just have `'extract_features.db'` and `'extract_features.exe'`.

Do you have any recommendation about it? Or could you share your `'extract_features.bin'`?

Note: My platform is windows x64.

Answer (score 0):

the `.bin` extension is usually added to executable *bin*aries  on Linux platforms. As you are running on windows, try running your `.exe` file.
Should be just fine.